# Getting java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object

Tags: java, exception, rmi, unmarshalling

I am new to RMI technology.

When I am running the rmi client program, I am getting the exception : java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object.
I am using jdk1.5

The argument of the remote method is the Serialized object.

These are the server code...

This is the Remote Interface

```
package interfacepackage;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
public interface ServerInterface extends Remote{

     public void getOrder(Order order) throws RemoteException;
}
```

This is the server implementation class

```
public class ServerImplementation implements ServerInterface {
    public ServerImplementation() throws RemoteException {
    }

    public void getOrderFromCash(Order order) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("WORKED");
    }
public static void main(String[] args) 

        try {
            java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1234);
            ServerImplementation service = new ServerImplementation();
            ServerInterface myRemoteObject = (ServerInterface) UnicastRemoteObject
                    .exportObject(service, 0);
            java.rmi.registry.Registry registry = java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry
                    .getRegistry("localhost", 1234);
            registry.rebind("ServerImplementation", myRemoteObject);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

This is the class Order

```
public class Order implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int id;
private String name;
public Order(int id,String name){
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
}
}
```

I have the same Interface and Order class in Client also.

This is the client code

```
public class TestClientProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try{
         java.rmi.registry.Registry registry = java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost",1234);
         ServerInterface service=(ServerInterface) registry.lookup("ServerImplementation");
         Order orderObject=new Order(1,"dish");
         service.getOrderFromCash(orderObject);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
        }
    }
```

Could any one help me to how can I fix the problem ?

Thanks In Advance
Renjith M

Comment: Have you started rmiregistry ?

Answer (score 6):

The exception indicates that the server is not able to find the method, which is invoked by the client (the error message is slightly misleading). One possible reason may be that the server and client are running with different classpaths and that the code has been modified enough for the RMI interfaces to be incompatible.

Comment: What's misleading about the message? It says 'method not supported by remote object', which is exactly what you're describing here.

Answer (score 4):

Something's wrong here. Your `ServerInterface` has a `getOrder` method but the implementation has `getOrderFromCash`. I would check to make sure all the code is compiled and executed with the same versions of that interface.

Answer (score 0):

In ServerInterface you should replace getOrder with getOrderFromCash.

Answer (score -1):

Well it's a late answer but it may help the new users.

I am using RMI (Client and Server)
I got the same error and everything was correct, but what I missed is to define the function in the server's interface, while it was defined in the Client interface !!

I hope this answer will help u :)

Comment: There is no such thing as Server interface and Client interface in RMI. There is one remote interface. It must be the same, by which I mean bitwise identical, at the server and the client.