# Java database connectivity using weblogic server using type3 driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic

Here i am doing the database connectivity using type3 driver using weblogic server and oracle database.

I came across this error when i run my code

```
E:\abhishek\D drive\abhishek\advance\jdbc>java Type3oracle
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: getConnection, Exception = Une
xpected Exception
        at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.RMIWrapperImpl.invocationExceptionHandler(RMIWrappe
rImpl.java:102)
        at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.Driver.connect(Driver.java:182)
        at Type3oracle.main(Type3oracle.java:21)
Caused by: weblogic.rmi.extensions.RemoteRuntimeException: Unexpected Exception
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_1030_WLStub.getConnection
(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.Driver.connect(Driver.java:168)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Could not unmarshal method ID; nested ex
ception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Method not found: 'createQueryObject(Ljava.
lang.Class<LT;>;)'
        at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:234)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef
.java:348)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef
.java:259)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Method not found: 'createQueryObject(Lja
va.lang.Class<LT;>;)'
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.MethodDescriptor.getCanonical(MethodDescriptor.
java:197)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.getRuntimeMethodDescriptor(MsgAbbr
evInputStream.java:495)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:269
)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.dispatch(ClusterableServerR
ef.java:242)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatchRequest(RJVMImpl.java:1135)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatch(RJVMImpl.java:1017)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManagerServer.handleRJVM(ConnectionManagerSer
ver.java:240)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.dispatch(ConnectionManager.java:882)
        at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.dispatch(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.
java:453)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.dispatch(MuxableSocketT3.java:322)
        at weblogic.socket.AbstractMuxableSocket.dispatch(AbstractMuxableSocket.
java:394)
        at weblogic.socket.NTSocketMuxer.processSockets(NTSocketMuxer.java:105)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:
42)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
        at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
```

Here is my code

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
//weblogic.jar must be in the classpath and datasource with the specified name must be created and deployed and application server must be running


//type 3 driver


class Type3oracle
{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
Driver mydriver=(Driver)Class.forName("weblogic.jdbc.rmi.Driver").newInstance();

String url= "jdbc:weblogic:rmi";

Properties props =new Properties();
props.put("weblogic.server.url","t3://localhost:7001");
props.put("weblogic.jdbc.datasource","type3oracle");
//type3oracle is jndi name
Connection con=  mydriver.connect(url,props);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rset=stmt.executeQuery("select * from student1");
while(rset.next())
{
System.out.println(rset.getString(1));
}

}
}
```

please help me i want to run this program to connect to my table which is present in the database xe.

Comment: Probably something wrong with your classpath. Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946841/getting-java-rmi-unmarshalexception-unrecognized-method-hash-method-not-suppor

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp i have put the classpath right the code is compiled successfully but the problem occurs when i run the program i have put the weblogic.jar in classpath

Comment: is there anyone who can answer it

Answer (score 0):

Use JNDI to find the datasource then getConnection() remotely, which will give you the type3 connection.